# want to use value from onError, RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I'm using rxjava, retrofit2, okhttp3.

I just put Log.d to see how it works and Log is like below.

```
1. D/-- NetPresenter: checkConnectivity
2. D/-- NetPresenter: Observable
3. D/-- NetPresenter: onNext
4. D/-- MessageSetter: setMessage
5. D/-- MainActivity setText: setText
6. D/-- NetPresenter: onCompleted
7. D/-- NetChecker: onError
8. D/-- error msg: failed to connect to /192.168.0.27 (port 8081) after 5000ms
```

It should set TextView after getting value "code" which is set from onError.

That means #7 should be processed before #5.

I think it is because of timeout option when request connection but I have no idea where to fix.

Can anybody help me to figure it out?

Thanks.

class 1.

```
public void checkConnectivity(Context context) {
    Log.d("-- NetPresenter", "checkConnectivity");
    this.context = context;
    myObservable.subscribe(mySubscriber);
}

private Observable<Integer> myObservable = Observable.create(
        new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> sub) {
                Log.d("-- NetPresenter", "Observable");
                int connType = cc.getConnectionStatus(context);
                sub.onNext(connType);
                sub.onCompleted();
            }
        }
);

private Subscriber<Integer> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<Integer>() {

    @Override
    public void onNext(Integer connType) {
        Log.d("-- NetPresenter", "onNext");
        int code = nc.netChecker(connType);
        view.updateReceivedMessageTextView(ms.setMessage(code));
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
        Log.d("-- NetPresenter", "onCompleted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.d("-- NetPresenter", "onError");
    }
};
```

class 2.

```
public int netChecker(int connType) {

    final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ApiService.API_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);


    Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> result = apiService.getData("database");

    result.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    if(connType/10 == 0)    code = 0;
                    else                    code = connType+1;

                    Log.d("-- NetChecker", "onError");
                    Log.d("-- error msg", e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    Log.d("-- NetChecker", "onNext");
                    Log.d("message", response.message());
                    Log.d("code", "code :"+ response.code());
                    code = connType;
                }

            });
    return code;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advantage of RxJava is asynchronous. You can't predict order of evaluation. I believe you should reach MainActivity from "onError" method. I see, that you use MVP pattern somehow. It should help. If you provide more info about classes relations I could say more.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I think I can figure it out!!

Answer (score 1):

you can use .doOnError() method to do some action on error.
There is another method .onErrorReturn(), which intercept error and return some value instead so sequence do not terminate. You can use both of those methods.

Comment: Thank you Alex. it was helpful